# repeat sampling n times

Tags: python, statistics, histogram, sample

Suppose I have some data about balls of different colors. I randomly sampled 50 balls of the data and I got the proportion of each color. But I want to repeat this sampling 1000 times and get a histogram of the proportion.
I did the sampling but I don't know how to repeat it and get a total proportion(?)

My code for sampling is:

```
data_sample1=data.sample(n=50,random_state=1)
count1=data_sample1['Color'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print(count1)
data_sample1['Color'].hist()
```

How can I repeat this 1000 times, please?

Answer (score 0):

Question not very clear, but something along this line?

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
opt=[]
balls=['red','blue','green','yellow']
for i in range(1000):
    opt.append(random.choice(balls))
plt.hist(opt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this code just chooses randomly from these colors. While I have a file of color data. And the problem I need to solve is: Read the data and randomly sample 50 balls and obtain the proportion of squirrels with blue color. Repeat this 1000 times and get a histogram of the proportion.